# Why is this script showing errors in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public Text countText;
    public Text winText;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private int count;

    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        count = 0;
        SetCountText();
        winText.text = "";
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count = count + 1;
            SetCountText();
            SizeBall(other.gameObject.transform.Scale)
        }
    }

    void SizeBall(Size)
    {
        transform.Scale = transform.Scale + Size
    }

    void SetCountText()
    {
        countText.text = "Points: " + count.ToString();

        if (count >= 22)
        {
            winText.text = "You Win!";
        }
    }
}
```

The Errors only started appearing when I added the `SizeBall` function and when I made it fire the function, how do I fix it? I am new to C# and I can't find anything about this particular thing online.
It's supposed to make the player (the ball) gain the mass of what it collects, but instead it errors and I can't even play the game.

Comment: Well you can ignore the errors (and not read them), and then ask questions without showing the errors, all the while not learning anything or getting your problems solved.. or <insert appropriate course of action here>.... In short errors are the only tool we have for knowing what is going wrong, if you choose to ignore them, you do so at your own peril.  Please edit your question with the exceptions you are getting so someone can help you

Comment: your missing a `;` at the end of the line `transform.Scale = transform.Scale + Size`
However i doubt that is causing the error you are referring to are you able to post what the error is?

Also fix your formatting with function calls like `count.ToString ()` `rb.AddForce ()` `GetAxis ()` etc you shouldn't have spaces

Comment: Is the name of the class and the file is same cause i faced same issue because of that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general please always add your complete error messages with Stacktrace to your question. This helps us to make our answers way more on point.

---

Simplest first: After

```
SizeBall(other.gameObject.transform.Scale)
```

and

```
transform.Scale = transform.Scale + Size
```

you are missing a `;`

---

Then

```
void SizeBall(Size){...}
```

makes no sense. You are missing either the parameter name or type. From the usage I guess it should rather be

```
void SizeBall(Vector3 Size){...}
```

---

Also `transform.Scale` doesn't exist.

Only [`transform.localScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html)

> The scale of the transform relative to the GameObjects parent.

or [`transform.lossyScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-lossyScale.html)

The latter is read-only and returns the absolute scale with all according parent scales applied.

So it should probably rather be

```
// Or maybe localScale depending on your needs
SizeBall(other.gameObject.transform.lossyScale);
```

and

```
void SizeBall (Vector3 size)
{
    transform.localScale += size;
}
```